# Login form on homepage for back-end login

Tags: php

I am trying to add a login form on my homepage so that clients can use that to log in to my backend website in PHP where they can check the progress of their project. The way it is set up now is that the client goes to client.mywebsite.com and i would like them to be able to login from mywebsite.com instead. I was just wondering if this was possible. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use a "POST" or "GET" request.

Learn more about that here:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just provide the login/password fields for them at `mywebsite.com` and when the user successfully is logged-in into your system simply redirect to `client.mywebsite.com`.